# Copy all empty files into a folder with command line

Tags: bash, shell, ubuntu, command-line

I am trying to copy all empty files from the home directory into a folder that is on the desktop, using this:

```
find ~ -empty -exec cp {} /desktop/emptyfolder \;
```

However, I can't make it work.

Are there any other possible solutions to achieve this? Or maybe to write a bash script that could do this?

Comment: Why doesn't it work? You need to make sure that the files are 0 bytes.

Comment: I get the following message: 
cp: -r not specified; ommiting directory '/home/...'
However, when I include -r I get a different error.

Comment: Add -type f to the find command.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions, however, I still get the "cp: -r not specified; ommiting directory" message. Can't figure out why it doesn't work...

Comment: If you have added -type f, why is find outputting directories? You need to debug the output of find before adding -exec

Comment: Apparently, I was using d instead of f. Now it works. Thank you.

Comment: No worries. Ive added it as an answee

Answer (score 1):

Add -type f to the find command to force it to search for files and not directories and so:

```
find ~ -empty -type f -exec cp {} /desktop/emptyfolder \;
```